# Call Web API with multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

WebAPI

```
public ActionResult Save([FromBody] string SaveId, List<Product> Products, List<Category> Categories)
{

}
```

How to call this web API ActionMethod from Controller Action Method?

asp.net Core MVC

```
public IActionResult SaveConfirmedDocument()
{
var Body = new {
                    documentID,
                    Products,
                    Categories
                };
var client = new RestClient(Url);
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Authorization);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", Body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

Comment: Hi @AkashWaghmare, any updates about this case? The solutions that I shared should be able to help achieve the requirement, you can check if it works for you.

Comment: Yes it worked, but I am not able to Up Vote the answer

Answer (score 0):

> How to call this web API ActionMethod from Controller Action Method?

Please note that once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer available to be read again.

For more information, please check the [`[FromBody]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-attribute) that can not be applied to more than one parameter per action method.

In your action method, you applied `[FromBody]` attribute to the first parameter, to pass and bind data to `List<Product> Products` and  `List<Category> Categories` parameters, you can make request with data, like below.

```
var client = new RestClient(Url);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Authorization);

//to make the data can be bound to action parameters well
//please generate query string data based on your actual model class and properties, like below
request.AddParameter("Products[0].Id", 1, ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("Products[0].Name", "PName1", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("Products[1].Id", 2, ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("Products[1].Name", "PName2", ParameterType.QueryString);

request.AddParameter("Categories[0].Id", 1, ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("Categories[0].Name", "CategoryName1", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("Categories[1].Id", 2, ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("Categories[1].Name", "CategoryName2", ParameterType.QueryString);

request.AddJsonBody(Body);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, if you'd like to pass both of these data through request body, you can try to modify the code like below.

*Action method*

```
public ActionResult Save([FromBody] ProductCategoryViewModel productsAndCategories)
{
    //...
```

*Model class*

```
public class ProductCategoryViewModel
{
    public string SaveId { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

*Code of making request(s) with test data*

```
var Body = new {
    SaveId = "123",
    Products = new List<Product> { 
        new Product { 
            Id = 1,
            Name = "PName1"
        },
        new Product {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "PName2"
        },
        new Product {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "PName3"
        }
    },
    Categories = new List<Category>
    {
        new Category
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "CategoryName1"
        }
    }
};

var client = new RestClient(Url);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Authorization);


request.AddJsonBody(Body);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create new class like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{

 public string SaveId {get; set;}
public  List<Product> Products {get; set;}
 public List<Category> Categories {get; set;}
}
```

And change your  action to this:

```
public ActionResult Save(MyViewModel viewModel)
{

}
```

Just select what do you prefer - DocumentId or SaveId. It should be the same in the both places.